# jQuery UI make the effect less abrupt and jerky

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I have a little toggle sidebar that I am using jQuery UI. The problem is it is very jerky behavior. Anyway to may it look like a smooth scroll left/right?

I am trying to get the outer shell to slide smoothly like the inner container slides. Currently it is snapping once the inner div is finished easing.

```
$(".snapper").click(function() {
 $(".sidebar-wrapper").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
 $("#sidebar").css("width" , "auto");
});
```

Online Example.
http://frontendtrends.com/sidebar/

Comment: The cause of jQuery toggle animations being jerky is usually due to jQuery miscalculating the target width/height. The calculation is done by placing the element in a dummy element that mimics the parent and making it `display: block`. If the parent element or the element you're sliding doesn't have a defined width/height, jQuery might miscalculate it as smaller or larger than it should be. padding and margin on both the element and/or it's parent can also cause this.

Comment: I defined widths for both containers, and it still eases the content while the #sidebar snaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `auto`. change it to some fix value and you are done.

```
$("#sidebar").css("width" , "200px");
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsbin.com/otusol/4/)

CSS

```
.o{
   display:block;
  float:right;
  width:30px;
  border-radius:10px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:black; 
}

.out{
    display:block;
  float:right;
  width:40%;
  border-radius:10px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:black; 


}

.i{
  display:none;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:10px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:grey;
  margin:10px 50px 10px 10px;
}

.i2{
    display:block;
  width:100px;
  border-radius:10px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:orange;
  margin:10px 50px 10px 10px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.o').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('out',1000);

    if ($('.i').css('display')=='block'){
    $('.i').fadeOut('slow');
    }
    else{
    $('.i').fadeIn(1000);
    }
  });
  });
```

Comment: I have the width set in the css. I went ahead though and tried your change and it just made the sidebar smaller, but it was still jerky.

Comment: can you post the jsbin.com link simulating your issue.

Comment: @ndesign11 I think he meant a sample that will exist after you solve your issue.

Comment: @ndesign11 Check out the demo.